# How to share my whole repository on GitHub from PyCharm?

Tags: git, github, version-control, pycharm

I had pulled a module from GitHub into PyCharm. I have been working on my project on a local repository.

After some progress, I am now trying to share the whole repository onto GitHub. However, when I "Import from Version Control" and then "Share Project on GitHub," only the module I originally pulled from GitHub gets pushed into its own repository on my GitHub account.

How can I now push my whole project into that repository I made?
Or if easier, what is the correct way to share the whole project, not only the module, on GitHub?

Answer (score 0):

When you ["Import from Version Control" in PyCharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/set-up-a-git-repository.html), you would need to provide the path of your project:

> ### Import an entire project into a single Git repository
>
> - Open the project that you want to put under Git.
> - From the main menu, choose VCS | Enable Version Control Integration.
> - In the dialog that opens, select Git from the list and click OK.

But if that project has a subdirectory representing the module you had previously pulled, then that subfolder won't be added to your project repository.
You would need to add back that module as a [submodule](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules) (whose support is not complete in PyCharm: [IDEA-64024](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-64024))